# LWC Component Tabs are not getting refresh, when moving back and forth on different tabs in the Lightning App

Tags: lwc-dom, lightning-web-components

I created an LWC component with `lightning-radio-group` and added it to the Lightning App, it only shows which value is selected by the user.

As I selected value and move the back and forth on the tabs of the same application and when I came back to the LWC component tab, it shows the same selected value.

**The tab should refresh.**

**I am also attaching a video with this issue.**

Video Link:- https://www.loom.com/share/38563c06b3e244158b7fce8b257ac52a

**CODE**

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Radio Group in LWC">
        <div style="margin-left:3%;">
            <lightning-radio-group label="Account Type" 
                                    name="radioButtonGroup" 
                                    onchange={handleChange} 
                                    options={options}
                                    value={selectedValue}
                                    type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
        
            <br/>
            <div if:true={selectedValue}>
                Selected Value: <b>{selectedValue}</b>
            </div>
        </div>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import Type_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';

export default class RadioButtonsInLWC extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedValue;
    @track options = [];

    // object info using wire service
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    // Getting Account Type Picklist values using wire service
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: Type_FIELD})
    typePicklistValues({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            let optionsValues = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
                optionsValues.push({
                    label: data.values[i].label,
                    value: data.values[i].value
                })
            }
            this.options = optionsValues;
            window.console.log('optionsValues ===> '+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
        }
        else if(error) {
            window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    // handle the selected value
    handleChange(event) {
        this.selectedValue = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the values of your radio group? can share some code?

Comment: use this line to refresh lwc page.                    
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");

Answer (score 0):

I believe this won't happen automatically in LWC, you should capture event and add some code to react to that event (perform actions that you would want to see). Here is the doc describing the events available in LWC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_events

Maybe try with onhashchange event.